# Browserify - require() a conbimed string will not build the module into output script

Tags: javascript, browserify

if require()  a combined string path. this path of module will not include in output script
like:

```
require("./"+"b" );
//or
var path="./";
require(path+"b");
```

I have `a.js`

```
module.exports="a";
```

and `b.js`

```
module.exports="b";
```

if use `var b = require('./'+'b');` result will be:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports="a";

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
var a = require('./a');
var b = require('./'+'b');

},{"./a":1}]},{},[2]);
```

if use `var b = require('./b');`result will be:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports="a";

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports="b";

},{}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
var a = require('./a');
var b = require('./b');

},{"./a":1,"./b":2}]},{},[3]);
```

I open the issue: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/883

Comment: Browserify does not execute your code when scanning for dependencies.

Comment: is any way to overcome it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Require in browserify doesn't work variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434214/require-in-browserify-doesnt-work-variable-name)

Comment: @AgentME it is not duplicated, I am trying to load many .js files(module) from the folder to an array.  All modules have same APIs to implement strategy design patterns. Then I can iterate the array and throw all the module into same test code to testing.

Comment: `require` can only be passed a single string literal, as explained in the other question. Variables and expressions are not valid arguments to `require`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [aliasify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aliasify).