# Externalizing route paths using react-router

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple React Router Handler:

```
var routes = (
    <Route name="main" path="/" handler={require('./main')}>
        <Route name="page1" path="/page1" handler={require('./page1')}/>
        <Route name="page2" path="/page2" handler={require('./page2')}/>
        <Route name="page3" path="/page3" handler={require('./page3')}/>

        <DefaultRoute handler={require('./signin')}/>
    </Route>
);
```

I'd like to externalize the page1, page2, page3 properties in a separate file (say a json file) and iterate that within the routes. Something like this:

```
var routes = (
  <Route name="main" path="/" handler={require('./main')}>
    _.each (routes, function(r) {
      <Route name={r.name} path={r.path} handler={require(r.module)}/>
    });

    <DefaultRoute handler={require('./main')}/>
  </Route>
);
```

Obviously I cannot have such a construct within routes, what is the React way of achieving this?

Or is there a way to alter the routes via an api?

For eg:

```
routes.addRoute({name: r.name, path: r.path, handler: r.module}) ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it with `jsx`, but there is an error in your `jsx` syntax. Try this:

```
var routes = (
  <Route name="main" path="/" handler={require('./main')}>
    {
     _.each (routes, function(r) {
         return <Route name={r.name} path={r.path} handler={require(r.module)}/>;
     });
    }
    <DefaultRoute handler={require('./main')}/>
  </Route>
);
```

Comment: Thank you, that syntax did the trick. Though I had to do a slight fix to my original code, because Browserify cannot load require module dynamically (it does static analysis). 

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434214/require-in-browserify-doesnt-work-variable-name.

So final syntax is handler={r.module}, where r.module = require('page1')

Answer (score 2):

react-router just added top-level API for defining routes without JSX in version 0.12.2:

```
Router.createRoute()
Router.createDefaultRoute()
Router.createNotFoundRoute()
Router.createRedirect()
```

The doc annotations in the [Route.js](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/modules/Route.js) source and the detailed [commit note](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/commit/c5a24a5) are probably the best places to look while you wait until official docs and examples appear.