# String concat or interpolation on require() statement results in "cannot find module" error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying to access i18n assets in an Angular project I'm working on in TypeScript, and part of our e2e testing gets the language the app is currently in from a config. I would like to pass that language value into the `require()` statement so I collect the correct JSON contents based on which language is needed for that test.

This works:

```
const i18nAsset = require(`../../../../web/src/assets/i18n/en.json`);
```

This results in the error `Cannot find module '../../../../web/src/assets/i18n/en.json':`

```
const i18nAsset = require(`../../../../web/src/assets/i18n/${"en"}.json`);
```

As does this:

```
const i18nAsset = require("../../../../web/src/assets/i18n/" + "en" + ".json");
```

What could be causing this? If it makes a difference, my e2e project is using Browserify, and the Angular application is using Webpack.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but since the bundler never sees `en.json` referenced as a dependency it doesn't include it in the bundle.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434214/require-in-browserify-doesnt-work-variable-name/26434259) is probably what you're looking for. Looks like it's a limitation of Browserify.